# Difference between StringLookup layer and embedding layer in tensorflow layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Documentation of [`StringLookUp`](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/categorical/string_lookup/#stringlookup-class) says that it encodes categorical features to numerical features, while as per my understanding Embedding layers also do the same . I think only difference is that `StringLookUp` does a sparse vector transformation in which OOV values are marked at 0, while [Embedding](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/) layer does a dense vector representation.

Please help me understand the difference between these layers

**P.S Improving my question statement.**

From what I have understood ,`One-hot` encodings causes high dimensionality issues for the categorical feature having many different values.
However, StringLookUp layer with `output_mode =int`, will also result in dense list for `m` words (*only one index for one word `mx1` matrix*), resolving the drawbacks of `one_hot` encoding.

Still what benefit would I get , using embedding layer over stringlookup layer in a DNN model for supervised problem?

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you have a `StringLookup` layer with default settings. It will create an internal dictionary mapping each word to a unique integer value:

```
StringLookup

the  --> 0
fat  --> 1
cat  --> 2
in   --> 3
your --> 4
hat  --> 5
```

You could, of course, use the other output modes: `one_hot`, `multi_hot`, `count`, or `tf_idf`, which will create other representations of your tokens / words. For example, if you were to use the `one_hot` output mode, you could directly train your model on these representations without an `Embedding` layer.

What the `Embedding` layer does, as you mention in your question, is map *unique* integer values to dense vector representations. However, it is important to note that this layer cannot work directly with strings. That is why you usually map your tokens / words to integer values beforehand. A nice feature of the `Embedding` layer is that you can also make the vector representations trainable.

An advantage of `Embedding` layers is that you can use pretrained word vectors that know how to treat words in context, unlike one-hot-encoded embeddings.

Comment: thanks for the answer @AloneTogether , I do understand the internal dictionary mapping them for `output_mode = "int"`.  But wanted to understand the benefit of using Embedding layer over StringLookUp Layer.. I think if we use `output_mode="int"` , the resulting mapped numeric list for the categorical values will still be dense, resolving the dimensionality issue of `one_hot` encoding.

P.S : i am also modifying the question statement, as it was not so clear , apologies for it

Comment: The benefits depend largely on your use case actually. And are probably quite subjective.